# Make object follow mouse cursor in unity

Tags: unity, movement, mouse

I was watching a tutorial on how to move objects on mouse movement. https://youtu.be/7OJQ6MbHuvQ

this is the link to that tutorial and below is the error I got while scripting. Please watch the whole tutorial to understand.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the signature of the function you're trying to use

```
Vector3.Project(Vector3 vector, Vector3 onNormal)
```

you're passing it only 1 parameter. And this is the first problem. The latter is that a `Vector3` does not contain a `Camera` property.

Comment: He probably needs to do Vector3.Project(toObjectVector, Camera.position.forward);

Comment: think the same :)